# First React project creation

Tags: reactjs, npm, enoent

C:\Users\Priyasha\Desktop\React Projects> npx create-react-app booknet
I executed this command in my cmd.
I got this error
C:\Users\Priyasha\Desktop\React Projects> npx create-react-app booknet

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall lstat

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Priyasha\AppData\Roaming\npm

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Priyasha\AppData\Roaming\npm'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Priyasha\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-29T06_23_10_518Z-debug-0.log

I want to help from anyone. I am beginner for react.

Comment: Did you install the `npm`? Use `npm -v` to check.